# I tried to access cookie through $_request variable. It's not working. Why?

Tags: php, cookies, localhost

I've created simple member registration, signin & showuser pages in php. After a successful signup create_user.php redirects to show_user.php. Here is my last part of create_user.php

```
header("Location: show_user.php?user_id=" . mysqli_insert_id($con));
exit(); ....
```

Also, after a successful login it redirects to show_user.php. Here's the last part of signin.php

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT user_id, username FROM users WHERE username = '%s' AND password = '%s';", $username, crypt($password, $username));

    $results = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
        $result = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
        $user_id = $result['user_id'];
        setcookie('user_id', $user_id);
        setcookie('username', $result['username']);
        header("Location: show_user.php");
        exit();
        ....
```

to show the user I'm using request variable like this in show_user.php

```
$user_id = $_REQUEST['user_id'];
$select_query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = %d", $user_id);
$result = mysqli_query($con, $select_query); ...
```

**Problem is,** create_user.php is working fine. but when signin.php redirects to show_user.php it' not retrieve the cookie value from $_request variable. This the error Message "Notice: Undefined index: user_id in show_user.php" How to solve this?

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](//stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) Use [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: PHP provides [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them. And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet). If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Is the data available in the `$_COOKIE` array?

Comment: Make sure the result of `mysqli_insert_id($con)` is same as `$result['user_id']` because usually value of database calls are wrapped in arrays. So it may so happen that the value you are putting in `Location` is not same as the value you are trying to retrieve in cookie.

Comment: Yes. It's available in $_COOKIE array.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's because you don't have an answer. Cookies are sent to the browser through the header of your request. But here you don't have answer, you redirect to the show_user.php. Not sure of the behavior of PHP, but to be sure it's not that, instead of redirecting, just display something with a button to go to "show_user.php". and see what happens after clicking the button?

Comment: I'm a learner. Give me some ideas about this issue.